# WebRequest send file

Tags: vb.net

I am consuming an API and, in a POST, I need to send a file.

My function:

```
 Public Sub SendRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte())

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        Dim request As WebRequest

        request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
        request.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length

        request.Method = "POST"

        Dim auth = "Basic xxxxxxxxxxx"
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth)
        request.ContentType = "application/json"

        Using requestStream = request.GetRequestStream

            requestStream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
            requestStream.Close()

            Try

                Using responseStream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
                    Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)

                        Dim objResponse As Object = reader.ReadToEnd()

                    End Using
                End Using

            Catch ex As WebException

            End Try

        End Using

    End Sub
```

jsonDataBytes is:

Dim data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)

But, it does not work. Any help?

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? What does `jsonDataBytes` look like?

Comment: When I try to FIle.ReadAllBytes(filePath), it returns: System.ArgumentException: 'URI formats are not supported.'

Comment: And the value of `filePath` is..

Comment: The filePath is an image link.. htpp.. end ends with image.png

Comment: So you know when the error message says "you can't pass a URL to File.ReadAllBytes" ...

Comment: Send with local path, it returns: Unsupported Media Type. The image format is suportted (PNG) and the API says also that the image file must be in multipart/form-data. Is there missing something for that?

Comment: Yes, I was going to say that typically there are a couple of ways we upload files to a REST endpoint that consumes json: we either send a multipart form, mixing json with binary or encoded data or we base64 encode the binary and send it in the json. As you're indicating your service expects a multipart form, that's what you'll need to send

Comment: Ok.. In the documentation, it's said the the body params is a "logo" as a file. How, then, to send it as a multipart form?

Comment: https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/09/04/handling-multipart-requests-with-json-and-file-uploads-in-asp-net-core/ for example